# Chrome extension web server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webserver

I would like to ask, is it possible to store a chrome extension on a web server?

I have tried storing it on a file server, but I would like to know if it's feasible to do it on a web server.

Any suggestions and suggested links would be greatly appreciated; thanks!

Comment: You can store pretty much anything you want on a server. Do you mean can users install self-hosted extensions from your server?

Comment: I would like it to be installed like the way you install extension from the google store which is, it is directly installed on your browser after download. But I think the only way is to packed the extension and download it first and install it manually.

Comment: Google used to allow this but no longer allows it Except for google apps domains.